# Trying to make while loop box C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a box using a while loop in c sharp, but it isn't working. I am a beginner to C# so help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
using System;

namespace whilebox2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            while (x <= number)
            {
                x++;
                while (y <= number)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    y++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

If inputted 5.

Comment: Get a piece of paper and try to solve the problem, once you figure out the algorithm, try translating to C# and update your question with your attempt, the new output, and the expected output

Comment: define *"it isn't working"*

Comment: Need an expected output example

Comment: The example output is at the bottom. I want it to print out a box of asterixis.

Comment: If you are new to C#, learning how to use the [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) is an invaluable skill that lets you troubleshoot many problems yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your y value again to 0 after finishing the while loop like this:

```
while (x <= number)
{
    x++;
    while (y <= number)
    {
        y++;
        Console.Write("*");
   
    }
    y = 0;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't reset `y` in the inner loop. On the second iteration the loop will only be executed once which is what you are seeing.

So just add `y = 0;` before `while (y <= number)`